# how to find max/min value in array in java without using functions

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author JEEWAT RAM
 */
public class Task5lab8 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter range of numbers you want in array:");

        int a = in.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[a];
        System.out.println("enter all numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

            numbers[i] = in.nextInt();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
int max = numbers[0];
int min = max;

for (int n : numbers) {
    if (n > max) {
        max = n;
    }
    if (n < min) {
        min = n;
    }
}
```